# Proving a complex set is open in Analysis

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that the following set is open:
$$
H=\left\{\left. z \in \mathbb{C} \right| \mathcal{Re}(z)>−2/5\right\}
$$
Just not sure how to prove this. please help. thanks

Comment: What do you know about open sets in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Try drawing the set - once you do that, it should be apparent that any point in the set is, because of the strict inequality, in the interior of the set.

Comment: Just prove that for each $z \in H$ you can find a ball $\mathcal{B}(z,\epsilon), \; \epsilon > 0$ such that each $t \in \mathcal{B}(z,\epsilon) \in H$

Comment: What is your definition of open?

Answer (score 2):

Use the definition of an open set; $H$
 is open if for any $z_0 \in H$, there is some neighbourhood of $z_0$ where all the points in that neighbourhood also belong to $H$. Usually we take the neighbourhood to be some disk centred at $z_0$.

Take some point $z_0 \in H$. We know that $\mathcal{Re}(z_0) \gt \frac{-2}{5}$

The inequality is strict, so we can always get closer to $\frac{-2}{5}$ from $\mathcal{Re}(z_0)$. That is, there must exist some positive $r$ such that $\mathcal{Re}(z_0) - r \gt \frac{-2}{5}$.  Take $r$ as the radius and $z_0$ as the centre of your neighbourhood. Now think about whether every point in this neighbourhood is also in $H$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

A set $A$ is open if $A \cap \partial A = \emptyset$. What is $\partial H$?